# Glassfish V3 SSL configuration CipherSuites may not be null at

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have configured SSL with glassfish V3
i have followed this  http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/
but now on console i am getting following exception constantly but on front end it works fine.

SEVERE: ProtocolChain exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CipherSuites may not be null at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.(CipherSuiteList.java:58) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLEngineImpl.java:1696) at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:358)

Comment: can we apply SSL to some pages only?